Numerical relativity and spin weighted spherical harmonics of spin -2
Why do the polarization modes of gravitational waves get expanded into spin weighted spherical harmonics of spin -2 for numerical simulations?
For example in this paper of the sxs catalogue they do this:
The SXS Collaboration catalog of binary black hole simulations
Why shouldn‘t I calculate the waveform directly on a grid on the sphere?
Does the expansion into spin weighted spherical harmonics have some special properties for the interpolation of the waveforms?

Let's start with:

Why shouldn‘t I calculate the waveform directly on a grid on the sphere?

The answer is convergence. It is generally beneficial to store the information in some smooth function as the coefficients of some suitably chosen basis of functions. If the function is smooth such coefficients tend to decay exponentially meaning you only need a relatively small number of coefficients to obtain (almost) full information on the distribution.
For smooth (scalar) functions on a sphere the optimal basis tends to be (scalar) spherical harmonics.
However, the gravitational waveform at (future null) infinity is not a scalar function. Gravitational waves have a polarization in addition to an amplitude. Consequently, we have at each point an amplitude and a direction of the polarization. This information can be encode in a complex valued function on the sphere, with the amplitude giving the amplitude of the wave, and the phase encodes the direction of the polarization.
This encoding needs to capture the fact a GW observatory rotated 180 degree around the direction of observation, will observe exactly same polarization of the GW, or equivalently that rotating the detector by a full turn will cycle through the full polarization twice. This last fact means that the gravitational wave strain at future null infinity is a spin-weight +/-2 function.
The appropriate basis of functions to represent a spin-weight  +/-2 distribution are the spin-weight +/-2 spherical harmonics. These, for example, ensure that the appropriate regular boundary conditions are satisfied at the coordinate singularity at the poles of the spherical coordinate system.
